# Interpolate a string with bash-like environment variables references

Tags: go, environment-variables, string-interpolation

I have an input string for my Golang CLI tool with some references to environment variables in bash syntax (`$VAR` and `${VAR}`), e.g.:

```sh
$HOME/somedir/${SOME_VARIABLE}dir/anotherdir-${ANOTHER_VARIABLE}
```

What is the most efficient way to interpolate this string by replacing environemnt variables references with actual values?
For previous example it can be:

```sh
/home/user/somedir/4dir/anotherdir-5
```

if `HOME=/home/user`, `SOME_VARIABLE=4` and `ANOTHER_VARIABLE=5`.

Right now I'm using something like:

```golang
func interpolate(str string) string {
        for _, e := range os.Environ() {
                parts := strings.SplitN(e, "=", 2)
                name, value := parts[0], parts[1]
                str = strings.Replace(str, "$" + name, value, -1)
        }
        return str
}
```

but this code doesn't handle `${}` variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [os.ExpandEnv](https://godoc.org/os#ExpandEnv):

```
s := os.ExpandEnv(
    "$HOME/somedir/${SOME_VARIABLE}dir/anotherdir-${ANOTHER_VARIABLE}")
```

You can use [os.Expand](https://godoc.org/os#Expand) for the case where the values are not taken from environment variables:

```
m := map[string]string{
    "HOME":             "/home/user",
    "SOME_VARIABLE":    "4",
    "ANOTHER_VARIABLE": "5",
}
s := os.Expand(
    "$HOME/somedir/${SOME_VARIABLE}dir/anotherdir-${ANOTHER_VARIABLE}", 
    func(s string) string { return m[s] })
```

[Run it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/73fxIwlbuwg).